# Yii2 LinkPager ЧПУ

Tags: php, yii2, pagination

Как настроить ЧПУ для LinkPager ? Задал правило

```
[
    'pattern' => 'news/<page:\d+>',
    'route' => '/news/index'
],
```

В action:

```
$pages = new Pagination([
    'route' => 'news/',
    'totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),
    'pageSize' => self::PAGE_SIZE,
    'forcePageParam' => false,
    'pageSizeParam' => false,
]);
```

Все равно LinkPager генерит ссылку вида

> /news?page=2

При этом сама ссылка вида

> /news/2

работает.

Что я не так делаю ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535932/180583

Answer (score 1):

Route подразумевает под собой "controller/action", а не url. Именно по совпадению имени контроллера и экшена Yii2 меняет ссылку. Попробуйте убрать слэш из роута

`'route' => 'news/index'`

или сделать так

```
[
    'news/index' => 'news/<page:\d+>',
],
```