# ЧПУ постраничной навигации в Yii2

Tags: yii2, listview, чпу, pagination, постраничный-вывод

Есть у меня на главной странице в контроллере sitecontroller экшен

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CourseSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

CourseSearch

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Course::find()->active()->with(['category'])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 2,
        ],

]); .............
```

Который выводит список постов через вьюху

```
<?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
        'itemView' => '_item',
        'emptyText' => 'Ничего не найдено.',
        'emptyTextOptions' => [
            'tag' => 'div class="alert alert-danger"'
        ],
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => '««',
            'lastPageLabel' => '»»',
            'nextPageLabel' => false,
            'prevPageLabel' => false,
            'maxButtonCount' => 5,
        ],
]); ?>
```

И постраничная навигация когда переходишь например на вторую страницу выдает вот такой вид:

```
mysite.ru/?page=2&per-page=2
```

Вот как сделать чтобы страницы выводились `mysite.ru/page-2`

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'page-<page:\d+>-<per-page:\d+>' => 'site/index',
            '' => 'site/index',
            '<action:login|logout|signup|contact|about|request-password-reset>' => 'site/<action>',
            '<slug:[\w_\-]+>' => 'site/category',
            '<category:[\w]+>/<slug:[\w_\-]+>' => 'site/view',
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем `config/web.php` и добавляем в components:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/page-<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     ],
//Далее какой-то код.
],
```

Код рабочий, если возникнут какие-то проблемы, выложите `config/web.php` и мы поможем.

Comment: `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/page-<page:\d+>/per-page-<per-page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',` Можно добавить первой строкой, что бы ?per-page=2 тоже формировалось в ЧПУ

Comment: А может он не хочет? Или хочет сделать per_page-hello-world:<per-page:\d+>? Все случаи описать? Я ответил по делу.

Comment: Вот такой у мен конфиг получился и сейчас все работает, у меня выводится все на главной, посты и вижет категорий

Comment: Код дописал в вопросе

Comment: Так отметьте ответ решением, раз все работает.